# How to get DrawingVisual area

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing

I have a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) like this:

```
Rect MyRect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(100, 100));
DrawingVisual MyVisual = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext context = MyVisual.RenderOpen()) {
context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Pen(), MyRect);
context.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(50, 50));
context.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(2, 2));
}
```

I want to get the [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) which describes the area of the element, in this case a [RectangleGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) where Rect property is:

```
Rect(new Point(50, 50), new Size(200, 200))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would push the transforms before drawing the Rect, you could get the proper bounds by the [ContentBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.contentbounds.aspx) property:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(new Size(100, 100));

using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(50, 50));
    dc.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(2, 2));
    dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, rect);
}

System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Bounds = {0}", visual.ContentBounds);
```

From the Remarks section in [PushTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pushtransform.aspx):

> The transform applies to all subsequent drawing commands until it is
>   removed by the Pop command.

Comment: seems to work, but there are some cases in my application where there's a strange behavior (the result is {0,0,300,300}). See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451066/visuals-hit-testing) please.

Comment: Changed the answer to use ContentBounds instead of DescendantBounds. Sorry, but i confused the two. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I'll try, I have to solve the problem of the other parallel question.