# Bug in geometry Hit-Testing

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing, hittest

I have a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) element that rappresents a path which  geometry is described by this [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.90).aspx):

> "m106,59.3c0-1.98,0,0-4.95,0.989-3.96,0.989-13.8,3.96-20.8,4.95-6.92,0-14.8-3.96-17.8-3.96-1.98,2.97,3.96,10.9,7.91,13.8,2.97,1.98,9.89,3.96,14.8,3.96,4.95-0.989,10.9-2.97,13.8-6.92,2.97-2.97,5.93-10.9,6.92-12.9z"

To render the visual i use MyCanvas class, that provides hit-testing functionality:

```
public class MyCanvas : Panel
{
   public List<Visual> Visuals = new List<Visual>();
   private List<DrawingVisual> Hits = new List<DrawingVisual>();

   public void AddVisual(Visual Visual)
   {
       this.Visuals.Add(Visual);
       base.AddVisualChild(Visual);
       base.AddLogicalChild(Visual);
   }

   public List<DrawingVisual> GetVisuals(Geometry Region)
   {
       GeometryHitTestParameters Parameters = new GeometryHitTestParameters(Region);
       this.Hits.Clear();
       HitTestResultCallback Callback = new HitTestResultCallback(this.HitTestCallBack);
       VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null, Callback, Parameters);

       return this.Hits;
   }

   private HitTestResultBehavior HitTestCallBack(HitTestResult Result)
   {
        GeometryHitTestResult GeometryRes = (GeometryHitTestResult)Result;
        DrawingVisual DVisual = Result.VisualHit as DrawingVisual;

        if (DVisual != null && GeometryRes.IntersectionDetail == IntersectionDetail.FullyInside) 
            this.Hits.Add(DVisual);     

       return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
   }

   protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int Index)
   { return this.Visuals[Index]; }

   protected override int VisualChildrenCount {
        get { return this.Visuals.Count; }
   }
}
```

When i draw my (red) path this is the result:

[image]

Where the size of the grid cells is 50x50. Now i try to get visuals for example in this region:

```
MyCanvas my_canvas = new MyCanvas();
RectangleGeometry MyRegion = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(50, 50, 250, 250));
DrawingVisual MyPath = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext context = MyPath.RenderOpen()) {
   context.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(50, 50));
   context.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(2, 2));
   context.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Red, new Pen(), MyGeometry);
}

my_canvas.AddVisual(MyPath);
List<DrawingVisual> result = my_canvas.GetVisuals(MyRegion);
```

But MyPath is not in result, why? How i have to properly do hit-test?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if the Path is hit at all in your HitTestCallback (set a breakpoint)? If it is, what value does the IntersectionDetail have?

Comment: I edit the question (i forgot the transformations) anyway: IntersectionDetail.Intersect

Comment: @Clemens I may have found [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453095/rendertransform-vs-pushtransform).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like *hit-testing* considers the position of the shapes to which was applied a [reverse order of transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453095/rendertransform-vs-pushtransform). This would explain why my path is intersected only and not [fully inside](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.intersectiondetail.aspx) the `RectangleGeometry` argument of `MyCanvas.GetVisuals` method.

Waiting for a better response, i implemented the *hit-test* with a *not hit-testing* method, now part of `MyCanvas` class:

```
public List<DrawingVisual> GetVisuals(Rect Area)
{
   this.Hits.Clear();

   foreach (DrawingVisual DVisual in this.Visuals) {
       if (Area.Contains(DVisual.DescendantBounds))
           this.Hits.Add(DVisual);
   }

   return this.Hits;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Mike Danes (moderator on MSDN forum) explains in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d7221b3c-8f86-4c50-bff7-61dbdf2611d9) thread:

> *"Is it really possible that this is a bug in geometry hit-testing?"*
>
> I'm 99% sure this is a bug. Drawing and hit testing should use the same transform order. The reason it works correctly with TransformGroup is because this way you only push only one transform in the drawing context and this avoids the wrong multiplication order in the hit test drawing context.
> Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that the order used in TranformGroup is different from the push order.

Comment: Can you file this bug with Microsoft somewhere?