# Geometry HitTest UIElement in WPF

Tags: wpf, hittest, uielement

Is there anyway to hit test an uielement using Geometry in WPF? I tried `VisualTreeHelper`, but it doesn't work. `UIElement` could raise mouse down event if a the mouse click on it with a point.

However, I would like to raise an event if a geometry intersect the an `UIElement`. How could I do so?

```
public class MyUI : UIElement
{
    protected override void OnReder(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(..., new Rect(12,12,120,120));
        ...
    }
}

MyUI ui = new MyUI();
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(ui);

EllipseGeometry eg = new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(24,24,40,40));

VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(grid, null, HitTestResult, new GeometryHitTestParameters(eg));

if (results.Count > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Hit Count = "+results.ToString());

...

List<DependencyObject> results;

public HitTestResultBehavior HitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    results.Add(result.VisualHit);
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

Comment: You still haven't said what exactly doesn't work or what error you get, but if i assume a few things i get your sample code running. See my edited answer.

Comment: If you are using transformations, this question/answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451066/bug-in-geometry-hit-testing

Answer (score 2):

Try [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx) with a [GeometryHitTestParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx) for the `hitTestParameters` argument.

Read about [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).

If all you need is a larger sensitive area for mouse input, you might add a transparent shape (e.g. a circle) to your control's visual tree.

EDIT: Your sample code works for me, provided that i add or assume a few things:

First, DrawRectangle in MyUI.OnRender() uses a Brush to fill the rectangle. This could also be a transparent Brush.

```
dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, null, new Rect(12, 12, 120, 120));
```

Second, `results` gets initialized somewhere:

```
private List<DependencyObject> results = new List<DependencyObject>();
```

Third, the MessageBox displays something sensible:

```
if (results.Count > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hit Count = {0}", results.Count));
}
```

Comment: Of course it works. You should better say "it doesn't work for me" or "i couldn't manage to get it work".

Comment: You could perhaps explain what you tried to do with VisualTreeHelper and what exactly didn't work as you expected.